# Navigation Properties of Entities in EF Core

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

See example entities:

```
Customer
    * Id
    * Name

Product
    * Id
    * Name
    * Price

PurchaseOrder
    * Id
    * CustomerId
    * Customer

PurchaseOrderItem
    * Id
    * PurchaseOrderId
    * PurchaseOrder
    * ProductId
    * Product
    * Quantity
    * Price
```

As you can see, `PurchaseOrder` is referencing `Customer` and `PurchaseOrderItem` is referencing `PurchaseOrder` and `Product`.

My question is, should the referenced entities like `Customer`,  `Product` and `PurchaseOrder` have navigation properties? See the modified entities:

```
Customer
    * Id
    * Name
    * PurchaseOrders (list) <----- added

Product
    * Id
    * Name
    * Price
    * PurchaseOrderItems (list) <----- added

PurchaseOrder
    * Id
    * CustomerId
    * Customer
    * PurchaseOrderItems (list) <----- added
```

In the case of `PurchaseOrder`, I'm convinced that the navigation property `PurchaseOrderItems` should be included because I consider them "parts" of `PurchaseOrder`, but is there a guidelines on when to include navigation properties? `Product` having `PurchaseOrderItems` properties don't make sense at the moment.

My **second** question is, if I don't include navigation properties, what implications will I possibly face, specifically in EF Core? One thing I could think of is manually joining the list of entities like `Product` and `PurchaseOrerItem` which is a bit tedious in my opinion.

**Third**, is it wrong to include navigation properties every time even if they look meaningless?

If you would decide to close this question due to unclear questions or any other reason, please, at least guide me to the right direction first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there a guidelines on when to include navigation properties?

For 1-Many relationships

Always have a singleton navigation property on entities with Foreign Keys.

Usually use collection navigation properties.  They are a convenience, but you'll typically end up using them.  The exception is in reference-type entities that can be referred to by multiple, unrelated entities.  Examples are things like Location, Organization, Currency, etc.